# Ubuntu doesn't boot from live cd

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, dual-boot

i boot ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a live cd, it shows me the purples screen of ubuntu then it shows a black screen, it freezes and never boot, note that i have downloaded ubuntu 3 times and burned it on 3 dvds and it doesn't work, something is wrong.

i tried all types of burning and also tried using a usb, nothing worked, someone told me that it's because i don't have an nvidia graphic card, in fact i have intel r graphic card,  would that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the Alternate release?

Comment: @Mitch no, should i try it? why?

Comment: Yes.  Its text based installation, but the final outcome is the same.  [Alternate install CD](http://ftp.ticklers.org/releases.ubuntu.org/releases/12.04/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I also have, that is a problem, is not the iso that you downloaded, but it is the DVD's you have the can be a problem.

One - you burn the iso to the DVD way to fast, and the burn session skips some files during burn session.
Secondly, that DVD is corrupted and can't read the DVD

If you can - try using a USB flash drive, it is way faster and more efficient.

The CD/DVD most time have problems. Burn it at a slow pace like 2x and not the fasted. That will make sure of accurate burning of files onto the DVD

Comment: i tried all types of burning and also tried using a usb, nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with UBUNTU 13.04- my laptop would not boot from the live cd AT ALL...

I found out that you have to burn the downloaded ISO image file to the cd/dvd as an image and not just as a normal file.

The boot up will then mount the image and boot up from it and ask if you want to try UBUNTU or INSTALL it.  With the try option, UBUNTU will run from the live cd without affecting anything on you current system.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in [more than one place](http://askubuntu.com/a/323754). When tempted to do so, typically: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.